# How to compile c11 iso standard code with g++ compiler

Tags: g++

System Details:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"


$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which parts of C++11 you wish you use, you need to pass in an extra switch:

```
-std=c++0x
```

g++ 4.7 and later use:

```
-std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11
```

A programming specific question such as this would probably be better suited to stackoverflow.com.

http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html